# SSH Terminal Environment

Tags: ssh, terminal, pytorch

```
[I 2020-12-09 09:15:49,277] Trial 2 finished with value: 0.678097665309906 and parameters: {'num_filters1': 16, 'num_filters2': 16, 'kernel_size': 6, 'dropout_rate': 0.5876482728988799, 'optimizer': 'RMSprop', 'lr': 9.014890468942645e-05, 'Weight_decay': 2.6662100371168874e-09}. Best is trial 1 with value: 0.6492913365364075.
/home/shar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/optuna/structs.py:27: FutureWarning: `structs` is deprecated. Classes have moved to the following modules. `structs.StudyDirection`->`study.StudyDirection`, `structs.StudySummary`->`study.StudySummary`, `structs.FrozenTrial`->`trial.FrozenTrial`, `structs.TrialState`->`trial.TrialState`, `structs.TrialPruned`->`exceptions.TrialPruned`.
  warnings.warn(_message, FutureWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OptunaTest", line 573, in <module>
    n_instances, n_features, scores = run_analysis()
  File "OptunaTest", line 354, in run_analysis
    pruned_trials = [t for t in study.trials if t.state == optuna.structs.TrialState.PRUNED]
  File "OptunaTest", line 354, in <listcomp>
    pruned_trials = [t for t in study.trials if t.state == optuna.structs.TrialState.PRUNED]
  File "/home/shar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/optuna/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._load(), item)
  File "/home/shar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/optuna/__init__.py", line 49, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self._name)
  File "/home/shar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/shar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/optuna/structs.py", line 41, in <module>
    "This class was moved to :mod:`~optuna.trial`. Please use "
  File "/home/shar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/optuna/_deprecated.py", line 77, in deprecated
    removed_version = _get_removed_version_from_deprecated_version(deprecated_version)
  File "/home/shar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/optuna/_deprecated.py", line 39, in _get_removed_version_from_deprecated_version
    return "{}.0.0".format(parsed_deprecated_version.major + 2)
AttributeError: 'Version' object has no attribute 'major'
```

I somehow screwed up the SSH terminal pytorch environment and it's not able to find the attribute major for version object.

The code is able to run but towards the end the error above appeared. I reinstalled the torch package and the issue is still not resolved.

Anyone able to advise how to fix it?